# Are self signed certificates considered invalid?

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed, restkit-0.20

So we have been asked to use HTTP SSL with our current APP and i am not the most knowledgable about the whole deal, and with some frustration and much...much trial and error we got it connecting the server...However we had to set it so that it allows invalid certificates, and we are also using a self signed certificate. so as the title clearly states, are self signed certs always considered invalid?

Some more info, we are using Restkit on iOS.

Comment: Out-of-the-box, most SSL libraries only accept certificates anchored in one of the known root certificates, so yes, self-signed is "invalid" unless the user (or app developer) tells the library otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

A self-signed certificate can be perfectly *valid,* but it isn't *trusted* unless the client has been told to trust it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The browser informed to the user that the certificate is invalid, when a self-signed certificate is detected. Actually, self-signed certificates are permitted under current web standards, so it’s quite misleading that describing them as invalid. Displaying it as Unverified might be more accurate description as it’s actually meant.

Comment: No it doesn't. It informs the user that it it isn't *trusted.* it isn't the same thing.